# Filling zero-value elements of an OpenCV Mat

Tags: python, c++, opencv, filtering, interpolation

I have `Mat` objects like this one below:

[image]

In matrices like this, some columns are intercalated by a predefined (fixed) number of columns in which values are all zero.

I'm looking for a filter to fill up those zero-columns with some column-wise linear interpolation. For example, the previous Mat will end up like:

[image]

Note that the original values of the non-zero columns are unchanged. In this example, the mat size is 3x7 but, in my application, the actual sizes are usually bigger than this one above, like 300x400 or more.

I wrote code to do that by myself. However, I'm wondering if there exist a streamline way to do the same operation using native features of OpenCV.

Comment: I didnt see a prepared feature doing this operation in OpenCV. You can implement an algorithm to do this and it seems you already did. How about float numbers, like 3.3, 2.7 ? How do you embed float numbers to Mat ? by using `<float>map` ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk the mats are CV_32FC1

Comment: Why don't you create the Mat with only the non-zero columns and use [`resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) to handle the interpolation?

Comment: @beaker even though the values obtained by  INTER_LINEAR are not exact the same, as I was looking for, I think this approach can fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your zeros are columns in a specific pattern, you can sample the non-zeros values and then resize (as described in the comments):

```
cv2.resize(mat[:, 0::3], mat.shape)
```